# How can I solve Value error in resnet 50 implementation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am implementing `resnet-50` on Kaggle and I am getting a value error. Kindly help me out

```py
    train_dir='../input/project/data/train'
    test_dir='../input/project/data/test'
    
    train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
          rotation_range=40,
          width_shift_range=0.2,
          height_shift_range=0.2,
          shear_range=0.2,
          zoom_range=0.2,
          horizontal_flip=True,
          fill_mode='nearest')
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
    
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
      color_mode='grayscale',
        target_size=(28,28),
        class_mode='binary',
      batch_size=32,
    )
    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
      color_mode='grayscale',
        target_size=(28,28),
        class_mode='binary',
      batch_size=32,
        shuffle='False',
        
    )
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights=resnet_weights_path,input_tensor=Input(shape=(224,224,3))))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    model.layers[0].trainable = False
```

I am training a binary classifier and I am getting the error below

> ValueError: Cannot assign to variable conv3_block1_0_conv/kernel:0 due to variable shape (1, 1, 256, 512) and value shape (512, 128, 1, 1) are incompatible

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using pre-trained weights on your model. You should set the `skip_mismatch=True` keyword on the `model.load_weights` function. After returning the model variable, please set the following code:

`model.load_weights(weights, by_name=True, skip_mismatch=True)`

Where weight is your pre-trained model weight. It should ignore any mismatch of your model and the pre-trained weights.

Answer (score 0):

You have given `input_tensor=Input(shape=(224,224,3))` while defining the `ResNet50` base model. But you are giving `target_size=(28,28)` in your `train_generator` and `test_generator`. The training image shape which `ResNet50` receiving i.e. `target_size` is different from what it expects i.e. `input_tensor`. Change your `target_size` to match with the shape mentioned in the `input_tensor`. Also, `ResNet50` expects `color_mode` to be `rgb` rather `grayscale`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of weights which you are using(weights=resnet_weights_path). You've to use latest trained model. Input Image size can be any as per pre-trained model guidelines

Below worked for me

```
n_h, n_w, n_c =(256, 256, 3)

weights_path = '../input/d/aeryss/keras-pretrained-    models/ResNet50_NoTop_ImageNet.h5'
ResNet50 = keras.applications.ResNet50(weights=weights_path ,include_top=False, input_shape=(n_h, n_w, n_c))
```